# Within a template class: Use a class method as a template argument for another class method

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code:

```
template < class A >
class XX {
  public:
  template <int (*CC)() >
  int bla (){ return CC(); }
  int stam() {return 0;}
  int f() {
    return bla<stam>();
  }
};

int main()
{ 
  XX<int> xx;
  printf(" this is %d\n", xx.f());
  return 0;
}
```

it fails on

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘int XX<A>::f() [with A = int]’:
test.cpp:14:   instantiated from here
test.cpp:8: error: ‘int XX<A>::stam() [with A = int]’ cannot appear in a constant-expression**
```

After thinking about it it’s clear. `stam` does not exist until the template is instantiated,  so it does not have a function address. When the template is instantiated then the instance is unravaled somewhere in the code and then `stam` gets an address. Thus the address is a not constant at compile time (although with some work it could be – but that’s not supported).

So why am I trying to do this. I could use a function pointer or virtual functions. In reality `bla` that uses `stam` (there are `stam1` and `stam2`) calls it a Zillion times and even a minor performance improvement (such as not using indirection) is welcome.

Of course there are solutions: Create `bla1` and `bla2` which are almost identical. Write a preprocessor macro. I am wondering if there is an elegant solution.

Comment: Even when the template is instantiated by `XX<int> xx`, `stam` still does not exist.

Comment: @K-ballo `XX<int> xx` will instantiate the class with `A=int` and with it, it will instantiate `XX<int>::stam()` and `XX<int>::f()`. The latter references `XX<int>::bla<&XX<A>::stam>` which will instantiate that instance of the method template.

Comment: @Tilman Vogel: No it won't, `stam` will only be instantiated if its directly or indirectly used.

Comment: @K-ballo I think, taking the address of a method of an instance of a class template (in the template argument of `bla` inside `f()`) is enough usage for instantiation. At least, my compiler agrees, see my answer.

Comment: @Tilman Vogel: Yes, it is enough for instantiation. I was just pointing out that merely instantiating a template does not cause all its member functions to be instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

This compiles OK:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

template < class A >
class XX {
  public:
  template <int (XX<A>::*CC)()>
  int bla (){ return (this->*CC)(); }
  int stam() {return 0;}
  int f() {
    return bla<&XX<A>::stam>();
  }
};

int main()
{.
  XX<int> xx;
  printf(" this is %d\n", xx.f());
  return 0;
}
```

The fixes are to use the correct signature for the pointer-to-method template parameter and the correct syntax to specify the method pointer. (In fact, you could leave out the `<A>` there.)

Comment: Thanks! It does compile. I assume the "this->" does not add indirection just helps the compiler out.

Comment: @user1766774 Well, you are calling via a pointer, so I guess, that call cannot be inlined but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that stam() is a member function, not a free function so it needs to be invoked with a "this" pointer.

Read this tutorial about pointers to member functions:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html